# How can I get an element without id, name and class attributes in red box using By?

Tags: selenium

```
<div class="bInputTab">
            <ul>
                <li class="onNow">网银支付</li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="type_onclick(1);">账号支付</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

How can I get the element in the red box using By?
Many thanks!

Comment: Please add HTML sample code of your target element, Instead of using as image part.

Comment: please provide some more details

Answer (score 1):

Try following xpath,

```
//a[@onClick='On click Value']
```

Comment: I change code like this. It throws error.
2018-06-20 18:16:26,306 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: <eval>:9:65 Expected , but found type_onclick
var b2cTab = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xPath('//a[@onClick='type_onclick(1);']'))
                                                                 ^ in <eval> at line number 9 at column number 65

Comment: @BelindaXu Any update so far ? I think, by looking your code its seems syntax issue with brackets. Also Have you tried with Double Quotes.  WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xPath("//a[@onClick='type_onclick(1);']"))

Answer (score 0):

This XPath should work :

```
//li[@class='onNow']/following-sibling::li[1]/a
```

Comment: I change to xPath('//li[@class='onNow']/following-sibling::li[1]/a'), it throws errors like this: 2018-06-20 18:20:25,817 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: <eval>:9:64 Expected , but found onNow
var b2cTab = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xPath('//li[@class='onNow']/following-sibling::li[1]/a'))
                                                                ^ in <eval> at line number 9 at column number 64

Comment: You should enclose this xpath in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xpath, tagName, all depends on HTML structure, You can find parent element, and search downwards:

1. `//li[@class='onNow']/following-sibling::li[1]/a`
2. if its only link in DOM `driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));`

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

The link text should also work as well

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("账号支付"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did not show the key structure of the HTML. It is because the element is not in the default frame. So I add the WDS.browser.switchTo().frame("frame_main") to the code, it works. 
Thanks for all of your help.
The reference is [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

1. The element’s locator is invalid

**2. The element belongs to another frame**

3. The element is not available in DOM yet